# Postgres incrementing null value in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, postgresql-9.3

In Postgres 9.3 when a field in a table has a null value the following expression doesn't work:

```
update table_statatistic set members = members + 1 WHERE user_id = $1;
```

However when the field has an integer value then this query increments it by 1 without a problem.

The questions are:

1. Why is this happening.
2. How to fix it.

Comment: Why? Because every expression involving `null` yields `null`. That's how SQL is specified. https://modern-sql.com/concept/null

Comment: I think you have that problem because you abuse SQL NULL. The correct semantics are "unknown", but you want to treat it as 0. Maybe you should add a DEFAULT 0 clause to the column definition (and add a NOT NULL while you're at it). Not only will that make your problem go away, it will also make all queries simpler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to use coalesce for checking null values

```
update table_statatistic set members = coalesce(members, 0) + 1 WHERE user_id = $1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `COALESCE()` instead:
The `COALESCE` function returns the first of its arguments that is not null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null. It is often used to substitute a default value for null values when data is retrieved for display

```
UPDATE table_statatistic SET members = COALESCE(members,0) + 1 WHERE user_id = $1;
```

Comment: Why do I need to use coalesce. Nothing + 1 = 1. Why is this happening.

Comment: A field with a NULL value is a field with no value. So you can't add 1 with no value Null is not a value.

Comment: This is counter intuitive and doesn't make logical sense, null means nothing. In many programming languages you can add integer to null  just fine.

Comment: can you tell me the names of programming languages?

Comment: @Jimski `null` is not `0` those are two very different things. `null` is the absence of any information. What if I asked you to add a chair to your spaceship. How many chairs would your spaceship have after that?

Comment: Gupta I can tell you that in PHP for example you can add integer to null. A-horse... I know that null is not zero that's why I wrote "nothing" above. Don't try to explain this using logic because your explanation is illogical. If null really meant no information it could also mean that Null field holds a big integer but we just don't know about it. And this is clearly not the case by simply looking into binary data in the field null. Your second explanation about strongly typed languages makes much more sense so I up-voted your comment. Thank you.